# The product of measurable spaces is the is also measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-sets

The question goes like this:

Let $(S,\mathscr{S}),(T,\mathscr{T})$ be measurable spaces. Show that $\mathscr{S}\times\mathscr{T}$ is the $\sigma-algebra$ generated by the sets $E\times F$ with $E\in \mathscr{S},F\in \mathscr{T}$.

In other words, $\mathscr{S}\times \mathscr{T}$ is the coarsest σ-algebra on $S\times T$ with the property that the product of a $\mathscr{S}$-measurable set and a $\mathscr{T}$-measurable set is
always $\mathscr{S}\times \mathscr{T}$-measurable

I thought that this was just the definition of a product set. So, I'm not really sure where to go from here. Could somebody help me understand what the question is asking?

Comment: You are right. This is the definition of the product sigma algebra.

Comment: In the place where you found this question, how is the product $\sigma$-algebra **defined**?

Comment: There are a few (equivalent) ways to define the product $\sigma$-algebra. For instance, we can define $\mathscr{S}\times\mathscr{T}$ as the smallest  $\sigma$-algebra  on $S \times T$ such that $\pi_1 : S \times T \rightarrow S$, $\pi_1(x,y) =x$ and  $\pi_2 : S \times T \rightarrow T$, $\pi_2(x,y) =y$ are both measurable. That is why it is important to know which definition is being used.